# Create button which takes to a particular URL according to data in Form Field

Tags: javascript, html

I've two input form fields and i want when the user clicks a submit button he should be taken to a URL based on the input in these two fields. For example if the input in the two input fields is A and B respectively the condition should be set such that the User is taken to www.mydomain.com/C in Javascript. I DON'T want the values to be appended to the URL like www.mydomain.com/a/b which I already know how to.

I have seen lot of questions on SO and Google on URL Generation but none was the case as mine. I would really appreciate help from fellow SO users. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? This would take you to the address when both inputs have the value 'something' and the button is clicked.

```
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">

<button onclick="go()">Go</button>

<script>
function go() {
  if (document.getElementById('a').value == 'something' &&   document.getElementById('b').value == 'something') {
      window.location = 'http://www.example.com/C';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The code looks correct to me. But for some reasons this is not taking to a URL. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AwesomeHat/fgxe1sn9/

Comment: Hey, it should work outside of JsFiddle , also if you check the Settings box of the javascript window in JsFiddle and change Load type to `No wrap - in <body>` it should then work also if you change the example.com URL to HTTPS instead of HTTP if you use JsFiddle over HTTPS.

And also always remember to check the browsers JS console if something isnt working! :)

Comment: It worked in JSfiddle the way you said. I'm a beginner so yet to learn many things. Thanks Mico :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function() {
    // TODO read your variables
    // TODO apply conditions and redirect accordingly
    if ( ... ) {
        window.location = 'http://www.example.com/C'
    } else {
        window.location = 'http://www.example.com/D'
    }

    return false; // prevent default submit
});
```